# Query regarding 64 Bit OS installation

Tags: windows, raid-5

I have raid 5 configuration machine with two drives C and D. In C i have installed windows server 2003 32 bit Enterprise edition OS. Now I want to install Windows server 2003 64 bit enterprise edition in C drive without changing any raid configuration.

Will there be any loss for my data in the D drive for fresh OS installation?

Comment: More suited for serverfault.com

Comment: this post is so serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't lose any of your data.